# Why shutil.copy2 doesn't copy file's stats exactly?

Tags: python, linux, copy

### Firstly:

code:

```
src = 'src'
open(src, 'w')
dst = 'dst'
open(dst, 'w')
print repr(os.path.getmtime(src))
print repr(os.path.getmtime(dst))
print 
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
print repr(os.path.getmtime(src))
print repr(os.path.getmtime(dst))
```

Output:

```
1357249388.8798938
1357249388.8798938

1357249388.8798938
1357249388.879893
```

I expect that after:

```
shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

this would be true:

```
 repr(os.path.getmtime(src)) == repr(os.path.getmtime(dst))
```

, but is **not**.

### Secondly:

Another strange thing is this:

```
print os.path.getmtime(src) == os.path.getmtime(dst)
```

gives sometimes *True*, sometimes *False*

Comment: Do 'src' and 'dst' exist before you run your test?

Comment: @JonasWielicki repr: because print rounds it to two digits after period, like this: 1357286203.86

Comment: @Lee-Man It doesn't matter if the files exists, result the same.

Comment: @xliiv You could still just compare withour ``repr``?

Comment: Sure, I can but it's a bit random, see the "secondly:" from the question post.